# Access LibJPEG functions through Magick++

Tags: c++, imagemagick, libjpeg, magick++

I use ImageMagick Magick++ in my C++ program.
I include it with

```
#include <Magick++.h>
```

I used it a lot and it worked well, but now I need to access some functions of the libjpeg library directly. How can I do this?

Magick++ already uses and somehow included libjpeg, but I can´t access the functions of it. I don´t want to include the whole library twice...

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <jpeglib.h>
```

See [here](http://www.ijg.org/files/) for some documentation. However, it might be more convenient to use the [Boost/Adobe GIL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/gil/doc/index.html).

Comment: I tryed this, but then there is the following error message: Error 1 error C1189: #error :  Something is very very wrong. This header must only be used under Visual C++. c:\imagemagick\jpeg\jmorecfg.h